# Hook Adding content after title

Tags: hooks

I need to add something after title in loop in single post and page, home page, categories.
This is for a plugin and i don't want to modify the theme directly.

```
function after_title($title) {

       if (!is_admin() || is_single() || is_page() || is_home() || is_category() ) {

            $write = 'AFTER TITLE';
            $after_title = $title.$write;
            return $after_title ;

            }

      }
add_filter( 'the_title', 'after_title' );
```

But it add content everywhere, in the widget or sidebare loop and even in my menu. I just want to do it in the main content, not everywhere.

I also tryed other ways but i had the same problems.

```
add_action('the_post', 'atr_insert'); 
add_action('the_content', 'atr_insert');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`in_the_loop()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop) to know if you are currently in the loop of the main query.

```
function after_title($title) {
    if ( in_the_loop() && ( is_single() || is_page() || is_home() || is_category() ) ) {
        $write = 'AFTER TITLE';
        $title = $title.$write;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'after_title' );
```